# How to load data to 1 table with 3 columns from a CSV file that has 5 columns?

Tags: sql-loader

My CSV data:

```
 10,ABC,10000,101,DEPARTMENT
 11,XYZ,,,DEPT2
```

I wanted to insert it into the table with 3 columns:

```
 EMPID,EMPNAME,DEPARTMENT
```

Comment: How to map the csv data to the correct column?   The above example will load the wrong data to the columns.

Answer (score 0):

In the control file, name the fields in the data that you don't want with a name that does not match a column in the table and call them FILLER.  FILLER basically causes sqlldr to ignore that field.  You should have identified which fields in the csv mapped to which columns but I will assume fields 1, 2 and 5 map to id, name and dept:

```
...
(
empid,
empname,
x1 FILLER,
x2 FILLER,
department
)
```